# Scala diverging implicit expansion compiler error

Tags: scala

Can someone help me understand the compile error message below?  I've been looking at this for a while now and I don't understand what's wrong.

```
  def makeOrderedLeafList(freqs: List[(Char, Int)]): List[Leaf] = {
    val buff = ListBuffer[Leaf]();
    for(u<-freqs) {
       val v = new Leaf(u._1, u._2)
       buff += v
    }
    buff.toList.sortBy(_.weight) //<= offending line
  }
```

Error message:

> diverging implicit expansion for type scala.math.Ordering[B] starting
>   with method Tuple9 in object   Ordering

EDIT:
Class declarations look like:

```
  abstract class CodeTree
  case class Fork(left: CodeTree, right: CodeTree, chars: List[Char], weight: Int) extends CodeTree
  case class Leaf(char: Char, weight: Int) extends CodeTree
```

Comment: Hi - I think it badly depends on the definition of Leaf - just copied your example and extrapolated that the class Leaf could maybe look like this: `case class Leaf (weight: Char, freq: Int)` and it worked fine for me. Also what scala version do you use (2.10, 2.9)?

Comment: Updated my answer to illustrate the class definitions

Comment: Which scala version did you use? - Or: could you try it again with Scala 2.10.1 and clean compile? - Seems to work with 2.10 as I didn't have any issues - and "Vorsprung" as well (see answer below).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Works for me on scala 2.10.0

```
import scala.collection.mutable._
```

then paste in the code you supply above.  `makeOrderedLeafList` compiles without error and seems to work in the intended way:

```
scala> makeOrderedLeafList(List(('a',8),('b',9),('c',99),('d',1)))
res0: List[Leaf] = List(Leaf(d,1), Leaf(a,8), Leaf(b,9), Leaf(c,99))
```

Comment: I guess this is a bug in my version, which is 2.8